# What are the limitations and disadvantages of Phonegap or HTML5 as compared to those of Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am curious to know if there are any drawbacks or limitations of using Phonegap as compared to using Android. What else can we do that cannot be accomplished using the other platform?

Why would one specifically choose Phonegap over Android (besides budget or cross platform compatibility) or vice versa ? I am looking for clear scenarios with justifications.

Comment: @bluefeet Why did you say this is too broad?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Full disclosure I'm one of the core committers to PhoneGap's Android implementation so my opinion may be biased but I like to think I'm fair.

To answer your question it really depends on what your requirements are. You've already dismissed budget and cross platform which are two of PhoneGap's key benefits. For instance if I never intended to target any platform but Android I would probably go with native Android development but if we were going to other platforms I'd pick PhoneGap. Also, I'd take a look at my team, are they hard core Java programmers? Go Android. Are they HTML developers? Go PhoneGap or pure HTML5.

Also, it depends on what type of application you are writing. A first person shooter, go Android. A table driven data applicaiton, PhoneGap is the way to go.

Anyway, without knowing what type of app you are trying to develop it's hard to be specific.

Comment: Let's say that  my target is to write a data-driven application which includes calling a web service to retrieve and upload data.The app also includes maps and also have to retrieve coordinates of a certain location. So do you think that Phonegap would be okay for such an application scenario?

Comment: Yes, that type of application can easily be done in PhoneGap. We have a sample application we use that does all of those things. Using XHR to communicate with web services, FileTransfer for upload, Geolocation to get the current location.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I would be interested to look into your code.Would that be possible?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post up that code right now but I'm all over the place answering PhoneGap questions. So if you have any other questions I lurk on SO and the PhoneGap Google Group.

Comment: I know the question is old, but what if I just have to build a photo gallery? It need transition effects for image change and something similar to Gallery widget from Google. How it performs on these things?

Comment: always depends of your app but in fact not an answer, phonegap it's really slowly with old devices devices you feel the app forcing to run that's a fact for me.

Answer (score 23):

> PhoneGap Pros

PhoneGap is an excellent solution in a number of situations:

**Multiple platforms:** Since the front end of the application is built using web technologies, a PhoneGap application with the exact same source code can be deployed across different platforms.

**Access basic native functionality:** If the application requires minimal access to the native APIs such as camera, geolocation and contacts PhoneGap allows access to these APIs with just a few lines of JavaScript code.

**Offline usage:** Although the app is built using web technologies, it can still provide offline functionality and has access to the browser’s local cache.

> PhoneGap Cons

Since the front end of the application is built in JavaScript, it causes a number of limitations.

**Data processing:** Native languages are much faster than JavaScript for data processing on the device.

**Background processing:** A large number of applications rely on background threads to provide a smooth user experience: calculating the GPS positions in the background, for example. PhoneGap APIs are built using JavaScript which is not multi-threaded and hence do not support background processing.

**Access advanced native functionality:** A number of native APIs are not yet supported by PhoneGap’s APIs.

**Complex Business Logic:** A number of applications such as enterprise applications are quite complex. In this scenario it is simply better to have a certain amount of native code.

**Advanced Graphics:** Apps that use advanced graphics which can only be accessed using third-party libraries are best done natively.

Comment: the article in the link doesn't appear to load?

Comment: I knew this would happen someday, this is why I copied the article and post it. The link contains basically what is being written in the post

Comment: "Offline Usage" is not a valid point here. Offlineability is for free, if you work natively.

Answer (score 4):

Benefits of building mobile web app:
1) Just need HTML5/CSS/Javascript skills vs Objective-C or Java. We made things even simpler by using Mobl (http://www.mobl-lang.org), a domain-specific language for creating mobile web applications that compiles to javascript/html.
2) Single code base for all platforms (iOS, Android, Windows 7, mobile web)
3) Rapid testing and deployment (up until you Phonegap it, at which point you're subject to App Store review conditions, etc)
4) With Phonegap, you can still take advantage of distribution and integrated payment via the App Store or Android Market

Drawbacks:
1) Poor performance, esp if your app is graphically intense, i.e. a game. You can implement caching or leverage some 3rd party solutions (i.e. Sibblingz) for native graphics acceleration but for the most part a native app is much faster/smoother than mobile web app
2) Lack of pre-built UI widgets, transitions, standard controls, etc. Your development time can take longer, especially if you want a polished-looking app with a native look and feel. You can try using Sencha Touch, JQ Touch, or similar tools with pre-built UI elements, but you'll probably still need to spend a good amount of time styling the app to look native.

So, should you build a mobile web app or a native one? If you're building an app that's graphically involved or involves any computationally expensive operations, go native for sure as the tools aren't quite there yet to make the job easy for mobile web apps. If you're building something fairly simple and you don't need any native styling or design polish, go the mobile web route.