# PhoneGap API coverage versus Native

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing some applications with Phone Gap and I see I have access to the Camera/Accelerometer/Compass and so on using the API.

I am wondering if the coverage of the PhoneGap  API is the same than if I am using Native Android to do my application or if there are certain methods or parameters missing and then I will have some limitations accessing the hardware...

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these links help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069937/1152549

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8213060/1152549

One of the biggest limitations of PhoneGap that made me switch to native was the lack of text messaging functionality.