# what is the limit and disadvantages of phoneGap

Tags: cordova

Hi I want to build app for iOS and Android,

I know that I can use phoneGap to write one and build for the two platforms.

Is there any disadvantages on the phonegap ?

I don't care the performance issue too much.

My project is focus on my website and show some information and push some notification to the apps.

That's all.

Comment: refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212547/what-are-the-limitations-and-disadvantages-of-phonegap-or-html5-as-compared-to-t

Comment: Too broad, not enough research done. Read the docs, browse the various forums, this question has been answered many times. Unfortunately, it all depends on the app and your needs -- therefore, it isn't something we can really answer definitively.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem when it comes to Android.

But for iOS, design, app crash, standards will cause.

App store dont accept apps which is just wrapped with web layer.
They have standards where you have to follow.Example, Buttons. You cant keep normal buttons in your iOS app. You have to follow the iOS guidelines how the button interface should look.

You have certain frameworks like **Ionic framework, Chochalte chip UI**,  where you get native interface looks.

Go and play with it :)

Thanks